# What is the proper way to handle Postgres server side errors

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using `psycopg2` to query from my Postgres server, this is the code that query:

```py
def execute_query(
        self,
        query,
        query_params=None,
        cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor,
    ):
        try:
            self.connect()
            cursor_id = uuid.uuid4().hex

            with self.connection.cursor(
                cursor_id,
                cursor_factory=cursor_factory,
            ) as cursor:
                cursor.execute(
                    query,
                    query_params,
                )

                yield from cursor
        finally:
            self.disconnect()
```

Sometimes without any server indication (normal CPU & RAM usage), the connection breaks.
When it does, it raises one of the following exceptions:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection pointer is NULL
psycopg2.InterfaceError: cursor already closed
```

I'm not sure if the proper way to handle those specific exceptions is to retry:

```py
    def execute_query(
        self,
        query,
        page_size=2000,
        query_params=None,
        cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor,
    ):
        try:
            self.connect()
            cursor_id = uuid.uuid4().hex

            with self.connection.cursor(
                cursor_id,
                cursor_factory=cursor_factory,
            ) as cursor:
                cursor.itersize = page_size
                cursor.execute(
                    query,
                    query_params,
                )

                yield from cursor
        except (
            psycopg2.OperationalError,
            psycopg2.InterfaceError,
        ):
            self.execute_query(
                query=query,
                page_size=page_size,
                query_params=query_params,
                cursor_factory=cursor_factory,
            )
        finally:
            self.disconnect()
```

I need to know if there is any way to predict those exceptions without catching it after it already raised

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, there are no magic tricks when communicating between two servers of some sort. And you cannot predict when they will happen those exceptions. So I will recommend firstly to manage the response when everything breaks. This are more mindset and general design suggestions than a deep dive into psycopg2 code.
I will add some quick tips I use, I hope this helps :D

**Keep track of your exceptions**

Expect weird outcomes when working with server-client applications, keep in mind that there are tons of errors you cannot possibly control and/or predict, but that does not mean you cannot classify them and escalate your code accordingly. A good thing is to separate your exceptions and handle them one by one.

**Have an unhandled exception behavior in place**

It could be retry every x seconds, it could be raise it to make it visible, or retry and store the traceback and exception name in a log to classify it later.

**Monitorize your server but do not worry too much about it**

Since it is for internal use, it is good for the sake of learning to try to find the reason behind every error. But there are lots of not so obvious factors that can meddle in your queries like: lan cables are bad, os in server crashes and quickly recovers, noise in wifi connections, concurrency, database size, etc.
So have your default error behavior in place and work for your method to perform not to be perfect in the first try.

**Transactions are your best friends**

I will start assuming that your queries fall into one of these two categories:

- DQL (Data Query Language): to ask things (SELECT). These are the easy ones
- DML (Data Manipulation Language): to edit data (DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT, ...)

(For more info on types of queries I leave you this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-ddl-dql-dml-dcl-tcl-commands/)

DML queries should **always be enclosed inside a transaction**, to avoid inconsistency when an unexpected error comes: [Transactions in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/transaction/)

If you are modifying data and something crashes midway transactions can help you by undoing what was left unfinished.

I hope this helps you and have a nice coding experience!!